# Calculus problem of finding the equation of a line.

Tags: calculus, parametric, word-problem

Find the equation of a line that passes through the origin, with positive slope,  and its tangent to the parabola given by :$ y = x^2 - 2x + 2$

My approach to this problem was to differentiate the equation of the parabola,  so I can et an expression, that determines the tangent line anywhere on the parabola.  I then got $2x - 2$, and I replaced x with a point (p), which is the second point of the line, where the first point is the origin $(0,0)$, and the second point being (p) which is tangent to the parabola,  I then used $2p - 2$ as the slope of , my line, and the y intercept of the line is zero, because the line goes through the origin.  The equation of the then becomes : $y = x (2p-2)$, and now I set the line and the parabola equal to each other,  and at that point is where I get stuck,  because I cant solve for $(p)$. I am pretty sure that my approach is wrong,  and this is why I needed help solving this problem.

Could somebody,  who solves this problem,  provide a full solution below? Thank You !

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Comment: @user ok sure, I will

Comment: Also since problems like this are frequently provided as exercises, responders don't want to spoil it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic line is given by $y = ax + b$.

If it passes in $(x=0,y=0)$ you can put this value in your equation and find $0 = a0 + b$, thus $b = 0$, and your line is $y =ax$.

The common points of the line and the parabola are given by $ax = y = x^2 -2x +2$ thus $x$ must solve $ax = x^2 -2x +2$. Rewrite it like $x^2 + x(-a-2) +2 = 0$.

This is an equation of degree 2. In order to be tangent, you need to find exactly one solution $x$ (not $0$, or the line doesn't intersect your parabola, and not $2$, or it passes through the parabola and it's not tangent).

You should know that such an equation has exactly one solution when the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$ (not the same $a$ of the equation, here it's just a symbol!) it's equal to $0$.

In our case we must solve $\Delta = (-a-2)^2 -4\cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 0$.

Rewrite as $a^2 +4a -4 = 0$. This is again an equation of degree two, we can solve with the well know formula and get $a_1$ and $a_2$. But only one of them is positive, the other is negative. Since you are looking for positive slope, you must take the positive one!

Answer (score 1):

At the point $x=x_0$ the slope of the line,as you said, is :

$$2x_0-2$$

And so the line is of the form:

$$y=(2x_0-2)x+b$$

What is $b$?

You did say it passes through the origin where $x=0$ and $y=0$. So with some basic algebra we can come up with:

$$b=0$$

$$y=(2x_0-2)x$$

Again, this you correctly executed.Now all that is left is to conclude what $x_0$ and the corresponding slope(s) may be. How do we do this?

We incorporate our final bit out information. That our line must pass through the point:

$$(x_0,x_0^2-2x_0+2)$$

Because it is tangent to our function at $x=x_0$.

And we get,

$$x_0^2-2x_0+2=(2x_0-2)x_0$$

$$x_0=\sqrt{2},x_0=-\sqrt{2}$$

$$y=(2\sqrt{2}-2)x,y=(-2\sqrt{2}-2)x$$

But you only want the one with a positive slope which is:

$$y=(2\sqrt{2}-2)x$$

So really the trick is to plug in $x=p$ and $y=p^2-2p+2$ into your linear equation.